# The newsletter info box is broken (apparently network-wide)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, newsletter

Our beloved newsletter box that shows up every now and then on the right side of your favourite main site appears to be broken.

More concretely it appears it just "copies" the image from the left continuiously until hitting the right side border apparently and also the background is shining through it. But I suppose a picture says more than thousand words:

[image: Crypto.SE sample]

[image: PPCG sample]

[image: Academia sample]

These samples are from Crypto.SE, PPCG.SE and Academia.SE, I suppose all sites network-wide are affected and at least on the Crypto one you can very clearly see that the site's background is leaking which looks like this:

[image: Crypto.SE background]

Comment: Looks like it's just the background repeating on the x axis (the "Love this site?" being part of the background image), caused by adding padding to the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Thanks for letting us know. This one is a side effect of some other frontend work we've been doing.

Fix is coming with next build.